# What are laws regarding falling meteorites and the angles of descent?

Tags: gravity, meteors, meteorites

I would like to know if there is any math / laws of physics governing the angle that a meteor falls on our planet.

I doubt it falls towards the center of the planet, from what footage I've seen, it forms a sharp angle with the ground (lets round down the earth as being flat for our purposes).

I am making a computer generated meteorite system and want to make it as realistically as possible. Lots of random will be a role in this and want to gather some min / max values for angle, speed, what friction does in all of this... Mostly the angle it falls.

Comment: If you think about it, there are not that many ways for a meteor to hit Earth directly from above. The meteor would have to go along earth's orbit at least some time for that. Meanwhile, a meteor that comes from an angle can come from basically any direction.

Comment: So basically it skips on the ocean of air, like a pebble would on a lake, until gravity pulls it at an angle? Makes some sense. I assume speed and mass counts a lot yes?